# The exactly same idea puts a rectangle along the centerline of it though cannot put an image in the right place, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to draw some kind of a "ray" with Phaser 3.

I started the experiment with a simple rectangle to represent the ray. Here is the code.

```
  this.add.circle(90, 290, 10, 0xf00000);
  this.add.circle(290, 190, 10, 0xf00000);
  let angle = Phaser.Math.Angle.Between(90, 290, 290, 190)
  let reference = this.add.rectangle(90, 290, 600, 5, 0x00f000).setOrigin(0);
  reference.rotation = angle
```

The line doesn't start at the center of its starting point.

[image]

I know the reason is Phaser draws the line (actually rectangle) starting top-left 90, 290 where the centerline of the rectangle is supposed to start at.

To fix it, I just need to change `y` of the top-left

```
let reference = this.add.rectangle(90, 290-5/2, 600, 5, 0x00f000).setOrigin(0);
```

where the `5` in `5/2` represents the height of the green rectangle.

And then I got what I want

[image]

However, things got complicated when I try to move something along the "ray".

Here is the code.

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game({
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create
  }
});

function preload() {
  this.load.path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/main/part1/assets/';
  this.load.atlas('bolt', 'bolt_atlas.png', 'bolt_atlas.json');
}

function create() {
  this.add.circle(90, 290, 10, 0xf00000);
  this.add.circle(290, 190, 10, 0xf00000);
  let angle = Phaser.Math.Angle.Between(90, 290, 290, 190)
  let reference = this.add.rectangle(90, 290 - 5 / 2, 600, 5, 0x00f000).setOrigin(0);
  reference.rotation = angle
  
  let bolt = this.add.sprite(90, 290-76/2, 'bolt', 'bolt_strike_0002').setOrigin(0);
  bolt.rotation = angle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

I just added 2 lines of code based on the previously working code, with the same idea

```
  let bolt = this.add.sprite(90, 290-76/2, 'bolt', 'bolt_strike_0002').setOrigin(0);
  bolt.rotation = angle;
```

the `76` in `76/2` represents the height of the bolt (image/rectangle) I put.

`290` represents the y coordinate of the center of the starting point.

The exactly same idea puts the green rectangle along the centerline of it though cannot put the `bolt` in the right place (along the centerline of the green rectangle), why is that? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To position the Image / rectangle, ... phaser uses the `origin`.
Fastes way to solve your problem is to use `setOrigin(0, .5)`
*([Details to Phasers Origin](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Components.Origin.html) )*

***Here The parameters explained:***

- the first paramater is the x - value: 0 = 0% = left
- the second paramater is the y - value: 0.5 = 50% = middle

> **Info:** If you set only one, like `setOrigin(0)`, both `x` and `y` are set to `0`.

**Here the updated example:**

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game({
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create
  }
});

function preload() {
  this.load.path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/main/part1/assets/';
  this.load.atlas('bolt', 'bolt_atlas.png', 'bolt_atlas.json');
}

function create() {
  this.add.circle(90, 290, 10, 0xf00000);
  this.add.circle(290, 190, 10, 0xf00000);
  let angle = Phaser.Math.Angle.Between(90, 290, 290, 190)
  let reference = this.add.rectangle(90, 290 , 600, 5, 0x00f000).setOrigin(0, .5);
  reference.rotation = angle
  
  let bolt = this.add.sprite(90, 290, 'bolt', 'bolt_strike_0002').setOrigin(0, .5);
  bolt.rotation = angle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> **Info:** In this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70803036/1679286, you can see how a different set origin alteres the effect of the scale property.

Answer (score -1):

You need an offset which with change its position in local coordinates and the medium of any object is `(width/2,height/2)` given origin is at top left.