# To get the target x and y for `tweens` animation, I used SOHCAHTOA, I'd just like to know if Phaser 3 provides a handy tool to do the job

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Followed the post [The exactly same idea puts a rectangle along the centerline of it though cannot put an image in the right place, how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70829188/12222879), I tried to move the bolt along the line.

here is the code

```
  let opposite_side = Math.abs(190 - 290);
  let adjacent_side = Math.abs(290 - 90);

  let adjacent_tartget = 123
  let opposite_tartget = opposite_side / adjacent_side
  opposite_tartget *= adjacent_tartget

  this.tweens.add({
    targets: bolt,
    x: 290 - adjacent_tartget,
    y: 190 + opposite_tartget,
    rotation: angle,
    ease: 'Linear',
    duration: 1500,
    onComplete: function(tween, targets) {
      targets[0].setVisible(false);
    }
  });
```

and then I got what I want, a bolt moving along the line

[image]

to calculate the target x and y for `tweens` animation, I used [SOHCAHTOA](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sohcahtoa.html)

[image]

I'd just like to know if Phaser 3 provides a handy tool to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy option is to make the image/sprite to physics-object and just move it, along the angle / direction.

**Here the needed changes:**

- add physics to the game config:

  ```
  ...
  physics: {default: 'arcade' },
  ...
  ```
- calculate the direction as a Vector

  ```
  let direction = new Phaser.Math.Vector2( 290 - 90, 190 - 290);
  ```
- add physics to the image *(and any object it should interact with)*

  ```
  this.physics.add.existing(bolt);
  ```
- set the velocity of the physics body of the image

  ```
  bolt.body.setVelocity(direction.x, direction.y );
  ```

> **Info:** for this example you would not need to create a `Vector2`, but I like to use them, since they have some very convenient methods. like `normalize`, `scale`, `length`, and so on. So you don't have to do the math, just know the right function.

**Here a working example:**
***Update:** Bolt now hits target (second circle) and `bolt` is destroyed on impact.*

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game({
    width: 600,
    height: 180,
    physics: {
      default: 'arcade'
    },
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create
  }
});

function preload() {
  this.load.path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liyi93319/phaser3_rpg/main/part1/assets/';
  this.load.atlas('bolt', 'bolt_atlas.png', 'bolt_atlas.json');
}

function create() {
  let player = this.add.circle(90, 170, 10, 0xf00000);
  let target = this.add.circle(490, 10, 10, 0xf00000);
  
  let direction = new Phaser.Math.Vector2( target.x - player.x, target.y - player.y);
  
  let angle = Phaser.Math.Angle.Between(player.x, player.y, target.x, target.y)
  let reference = this.add.rectangle(player.x, player.y, 600, 5, 0x00f000).setOrigin(0, .5);
  reference.rotation = angle
   
  let bolt = this.add.sprite(player.x, player.y, 'bolt', 'bolt_strike_0002').setOrigin(0, .5);
  bolt.rotation = angle;
  
  this.physics.add.existing(bolt);
  this.physics.add.existing(target);
 
  bolt.body.setVelocity(direction.x, direction.y );
  
  
  this.physics.add.collider(bolt, target, removeBolt );
  
}

function removeBolt(bolt, target){
    bolt.destroy();
    target.destroy();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> **Extra Informtion:** for more detailed examples on phaser physics, I recommend looking at these official examples: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/physics/arcade they cover most of the common needed function/use cases, and explain them very well. *(Better then I ever could)*

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very informative. How do I make the bolt disappear at  (290 - adjacent_tartget, 190 + opposite_tartget) as my bolt hits the target instead of going through it.

Comment: @yaojp the phaser physics has a `collider`  function https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Collider.html I will update my answer with a small demo

Comment: @yaojp I updated my answer I hope this help you, and explains the concept, a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code is excellent! Do I need to deal with the dead body of the `target` which might live at somewhere out of sight?

Comment: Yes, the object is still there, to remove it just call `target.destroy()` in the `removeBolt` function and it should be gone.